# Missing component (ACE0DBC.DLL) when I try to use pyodbc in python 3.6

Tags: pyodbc

I am using the 32-bit version on python and, although my computer is a 64-bit computer, I have successfully installed pyodbc 32-bit windows version. My Microsoft Access is also the 32 bit version.

When I query pyodbc for drivers, it shows both drivers.

```
[x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('Microsoft Access Driver')]
```

yields

```
['Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)', 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)']
```

Using examples in other places, I build a connection string "c" as follows

```
c= (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\users\815001\Documents\Database6.accdb;'
     )
```

I then try to connect with

```
cnxn=pyodbc.connect(c)
```

This results in the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    cnxn=pyodbc.connect(c)

pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  126: The specified module could not be found. (Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb), C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\ACEODBC.DLL). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I have checked the location and indeed there is no ACE0DBC.DLL file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE 16.

Where do I go to get it? I tried looking up ACE0DBC.DLL in the search engine on this web page and it yielded no results.

Comment: Possibly related to [this issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2874601/can-not-use-access-odbc-or-oledb-provider-outside-office-c2r-apps)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54920